# How can I replace 10k potentiometer with 5k joystick?

Tags: resistors, potentiometer, repair

My YAMAHA PSR S950 pitch bend is broken, and it got 10k potentiometer inside. 
Everything I got here is some joystick, and Arduino (if that helps).

Finding exact size 10k potentiometer is not going to help, as everyone sells them for $50 here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [service manual](https://elektrotanya.com/yamaha_psr-s950-s750_sm.pdf/download.html), the potentiometer is connected between the signals called +5DA and AVSS:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWBtAx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Replacing the 10k potentiometer with a 5k just means that it will draw a constant 0.5 mA more current, which will not be *any* problem what so ever. +5DA is connected straight through to the main VDD, so it can definitely handle it.

Comment: so, that means I need to put 5k resistor on my data pin on my joystick?

Comment: no , unless it is too sensitive.

Comment: According to the [service manual](https://elektrotanya.com/yamaha_psr-s950-s750_sm.pdf/download.html) the pitch bend pot is connected from +5V to Ground and its wiper simply goes to an ADC input on the MCU, so you don't need to add any resistors.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Awesome find, I updated the answer with new info